# How do I approach deriving recurrence relations?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

So I am stuck on the following problem.

```
Derive a recurrence relation for tiling a 2 x n checkerboard with 
a) a 1 x 1 square
b) a 2 x 1 "L" figure formed by chopping a 1 x 1 square off 
from a 2 x 2 square which can be rotated.
```

I was able to derive the fact that:

```
T(1) = 1 (you can only tile a checkerboard with a 2, 1 x 1 squares
T(2) = 5 (you can rotate the "L" four times plus place a square in each)
T(3) = 11 (you have 2 places where you can place an L (8), 
2 places where you can tile using 2 squares (2) and the 
case where you use all squares (1)
```

How do I go about creating the relation for 2 x n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Look at the end of the board. There are only a few possibilities:

- two $1\times 1$ tiles stacked vertically;
- an L tile and a $1\times 1$ tile in any of $4$ orientations; and
- two interlocking L tiles in either of $2$ orientations.

If you see the first of these, you know that the $2\times(n-1)$ board to the left of them has one of $T(n-1)$ possible tilings; that accounts for $T(n-1)$ of the $T(n)$ tilings of the $2\times n$ board.

If you see the second, you know that the $2\times(n-2)$ board to the left of them has one of $T(n-2)$ possible tilings; that accounts for $4T(n-2)$ of the $T(n)$ tilings of the $2\times n$ board. The factor of $4$ is because there are $4$ possible $2\times 2$ extensions with an L and a $1\times 1$ tile, depending on the orientation of the pair.

I’ll leave the last case to you. These three cases cover every possible tiling of the $2\times n$ board, so summing their contributions gives you your recurrence for $T(n)$.

Comment: Hm, I got t(n) = t(n -1) + 4t(n - 2) + 2t(n - 3), but I'm still lost on the reasoning of the problem. How do we know that 2 x (n - 1) boards only account for the T(n - 1) tiling( 2 x (n - 2) is for T(n - 2) ,etc.)? I guess I'm having trouble visualizing all of this. Are we looking at the part of the board we chopped off, or the remaining part?

Comment: @Shanty: What you got is correct. You strip off the shortest bit on the righthand end that doesn’t leave a jagged edge; that’s either a $2\times 1$ bit covered by two square tiles, a $2\times 2$ bit covered by an L and a square, or a $3\times 2$ bit covered by two Ls. What remains on the left is either $2\times(n-1)$, $2\times(n-2)$, or $2\times(n-3)$. We know how many ways there are to tile those lefthand parts: $T(n-1),T(n-2)$, and $T(n-3)$, respectively.